# Finding the Expected Value of a Random Variable Distribution with an infinite positive range for $x$

Tags: probability, statistics

> "Let $f(x) = (1/2)^x$ for $x = 1, 2, 3, ...$ and $0$ otherwise, be the probability function of a random variable. Find the mean."

I get that the Summation of all $f(x)$ equals $1$. Also get that the Mean is calculated with the Summation of all values of $x$ multiplied by their probability $f(x)$, since we're dealing with a discrete variable.

What I don't get is how do I combine these two rules to get the value of the Mean. Maybe I'm missing some Summation rule?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, it will be an infinite sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$S = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x}{2^x} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x}{2^x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} S = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x}{2^{x+1}} = \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x-1}{2^x}$$
(The last equality is due to re-indexing of the series $\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{2^3} + \frac{3}{2^4} + \cdots$.)

Subtracting the above two lines yields
$$\frac{1}{2} S = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x} = 1$$
so $S=2$.